# How can I return an observable in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I had a project that was previously on Angular 5.x and I updated it to 7. There is a particular instance where I need to return an httpClient observable but I can't figure out how it changed in Angular 7. It's giving me an error on the "catch" of the callApi function. [ts] Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable'. [2339] is my error

```
callApi(url: string): Observable<any> {

    return this.httpClient
        .get(url)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

This is all of the code in my config.service.ts file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

    private configUrl = environment.production ? './assets/config/config.prod.json' : './assets/config/config.dev.json';

    private _config: any;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }

    load(): Promise<any> {

        let promise: Promise<any> = new Promise((resolve: any) => {

            this.callApi(this.configUrl)
                .subscribe(config => {
                    this._config = config;
                    resolve(true)
                });
        });
        return promise;
    }

    getConfig(key: any) {
        return this._config[key];
    }

    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            let body = {}
            try {
                body = error.json();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            const err = body['error'] || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }

        console.error(errMsg);

        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

    callApi(url: string): Observable<any> {

        return this.httpClient
            .get(url)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your `rxjs` library to higher version and change the following code - You need use `pipe` operators from `rxjs` that might solve your `catchError()` issue - change your `catch` as `catchError`

Try something like this

```
callApi(url: string): Observable<any> {

    return this.httpClient
        .get(url).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Hope this helps - Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Angular 6 went from RxJs 5 to RxJs 6 and there are a few breaking changes.

catch has been renamed to catchError

https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

There is a compatibility library you can install for when you upgrade from RxJs 5 to 6 but it is better to modify your code to be RxJs 6 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `catchError` rather than `catch`, because HttpClient returns an Observable, consider that a subscription to an Observable has 3 callback parameters corresponding to the success events, the error events, and then a completion event when the connection is finished what it was doing (really you can ignore this one most of the time). So, your code could look like this:

config.service.ts

```
callApi(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
        .get(url)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError)); // adjust handleError function, as necessary
}
```

some.component.ts

```
this.configService.callApi('https://google.com')
  .subscribe(
    goodResult => console.log(goodResult),
    error => console.log(error),
    () => console.log('the api call is done!')
  )
```